# magento 2 how to make change on default module block directory for new custome theme develop

Tags: magento

i want to make some change in code file for my custom theme.
default magento 2 all module are located in vendor magento directory

in customer moduele default path is

```
vendor\magento\module-customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink.php
```

now i want to make change on this php file so where i should put no my 
`app/design/frontend/<vendor-dir>/<theme-dir>/Magento_Customer` ?